# Links in Express app missing API Gateway stage with Claudia JS

Tags: express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, claudiajs

I've deployed a very basic Express app through Claudia JS. It's working pretty well, but any links or redirects don't keep the API Gateway stage and so don't work.

For example I have the app deployed at http://example.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/production - that's the equivalent of http://localhost:3000 when running locally. If there is a link on that page along the lines of `<a href="/test">` that goes to http://localhost:3000/test locally, but through the api gateway it goes to http://example.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test - losing the /production part of the URL and therefore not working.

Is there a way to get Express to know that all routes need to be prefaced with /production?

The alternate solution is to use a custom domain, but that seems like a lot of hassle to solve what seems like it should be just a bit of config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to build the base URL;

`https://${req.apiGateway.event.headers.Host}/${req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.stage}`